# Global Extrema of $f(x,y):=\begin{cases}\frac{x^4y}{(x^2+y^2)^2},& (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\\0, &(x,y)=(0,0)\}\end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

Let's consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where  $f(x,y):=\begin{cases}\frac{x^4y}{(x^2+y^2)^2},& (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\\0, &(x,y)=(0,0)\}.\end{cases}$

We know that $f$ is everywhere but $(0,0)$ total differentiable with $Df(x,y)=\left(\frac{4x^3y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^3},\frac{x^4(x^2-3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}\right)$.

We restrict $f$ to the compact set $M:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ and want to find the global extrema on this set.

**My approach:**

We know that the global Extrema exist due to continuity of $f$ on $M$ and compactness of $M$. We know that $M_0:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$ is open so we can find all possible extrema by the first order condition $Df(x,y)=0$. This condition can't be satisfied as this would imply $(x=0,y\neq0)$ or $(x\neq0,y=0)$. If we take a look at $f(x,y)$ we immediately see that those points can't be extrema. So the extrema must lie in the set $M_1:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$. We apply the method of the Lagrange multipliers and finally get the equations:
$$
\left(\frac{4x^3y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^3},\frac{x^4(x^2-3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}\right)= (2x\lambda,2y\lambda)\\x^2+y^2=1
\\ \implies 2x^2y^3= \lambda, ~~x^4(x^2-3y^2)=2y\lambda\\
\implies x^4(x^2-3y^2)=4x^2y^4
$$

Here I am stuck. Maybe this approach is nonsense or maybe there is a trick  I don't see to solve this equation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use polar coordinates. The problem reduces to finding extrema for $r\cos^4\theta\sin \theta$.

Comment: @Andrei, is there no way to solve the equations?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to solve using your approach, note that $x=0$ is a solution to the last equation. Than $x^2+y^2=1$ will yield $y=\pm 1$. Suppose $x\ne 0$. Then divide your last equation by $x^6$. You get $$1-3\frac{y^2}{x^2}=4\frac{y^4}{x^4}$$
This is a quadratic equation in $\frac{y^2}{x^2}$.